# Are right-adjoints of a forgetful functor reflectors?

Tags: category-theory, terminology, free-groups, adjoint-functors, forgetful-functors

From what I understand, there is no formal definition of a forgetful and an inclusion functor, but more like "moral guidelines" with "good properties" of why we would call them that. Here are some examples:

- The functor $U: \mathcal{Grp} \rightarrow \mathcal{Set}$ that sends each group to its underlying set is usually called a **forgetful functor**. It has "good properties" like

  - It **admits a left-adjoint**, called a "free functor", $F: \mathcal{Set} \rightarrow \mathcal{Grp}$.
  - It is **faithful**.
- The functor $i: \mathcal{Ab} \rightarrow \mathcal{Grp}$ that sends each commutative group to itself but "forgets" that it is commutative is usually called an **inclusion functor**. It has "good properties" like

  - It admits a **right-adjoint**, called the "reflector", $\operatorname{Ab}:  \mathcal{Grp} \rightarrow \mathcal{Ab}$
  - It is **faithful and injective on objects**.

Now I am curious about faithful functors who admit both left- and right-adjoints! Here are some examples:

- Define the forgetful functor from topological spaces to sets $U: \mathcal{Top} \rightarrow \mathcal{Set}$. We can further define the *discrete topology* functor (a.k.a. free functor) $D$ and the *trivial topology* functor $D$. This gives us the adjoint triple $D \dashv U \dashv T$.
- Define the restriction of scalars (a.k.a. forgetful functor) from $R$- modules to abelian groups $f^*: \mathcal{Mod}_R \rightarrow \mathcal{Ab}: M \mapsto M_{\mathbb{Z}}$, where $f: \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow R$ is the unique ring-homomorphism. We can further define the *extension of scalars* functor $f_! : \mathcal{Ab} \rightarrow \mathcal{Mod}_R : M \mapsto M \otimes R$ and the *co-extension of scalars* functor $f_* : \mathcal{Ab} \rightarrow \mathcal{Mod}_R : M \mapsto \operatorname{Hom}(R, M)$. This gives us the adjoint triple $f_! \dashv f^* \dashv f_*$.

Now, I guess I should not think of topological spaces as a "reflective subcategory" of sets or abelian groups as a "reflective subcategory" of $R$-modules using the functors $T$ and $f_*$. One thing that comes to my mind why not is that both of these "forgetful functors", $U$ and $f^*$, are not injective on objects. This leads to my concrete question:

---

**TLDR**: Is it wrong to think of faithful functors that admit a right adjoint, like $U$ and $f^*$, as inclusion functors? If yes, is it because being "injective on objects" is a defining property of an inclusion functor?

Comment: Who says there is no formal definition of "inclusion functor"? It's what we call functors of the form $\mathcal{S} \hookrightarrow \mathcal{C}$ where $\mathcal{S} \subseteq \mathcal{C}$ is a subcategory (up to isomorphism).

Comment: If I understand "up to isomorphism" right in this context, that would mean that an inclusion functor implies being injective on objects. 

I'm starting to think whether my confusion comes from thinking an inclusion functor is of the form $S \hookrightarrow C$, where $S \subset C$ is a subcategory **up to equivalence**...

Comment: Yes, that would imply being injective on objects. Either way, I wouldn't worry too much about the terminology here. People will generally tell you when something is an inclusion of subcategories and refer to right adjoints, as, well, right adjoints, especially when the notion of "forgetful functor" is somewhat shaky :)